# div click is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this div with classname 'item', I want make it clickable and redirect to the page with book details, but the click event is not happening.

```
 <div id="results">
        <ul class="contents">
            <li>
                <div id="1" class="item">
                    <div class="center">1. </div>
                    <div class="center"><strong>ABook</strong></div>
                    <div class="center">Description</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="2" class="item">
                    <div class="center">2. </div>
                    <div class="center"><strong>BBook</strong></div>
                    <div class="center">Description</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="3" class="item">
                    <div class="center">3. </div>
                    <div class="center"><strong>CBook</strong></div>
                    <div class="center">Description</div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div align="center">
            <ul class="pagen">
                <li class="first active">1</li>
                <li><a href="#" data-page="2" title="Page 2">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-page="3" title="Page 3">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-page="4" title="Next">&gt;</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#" data-page="4" title="Last">»</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".item").click(function(e){ 
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
 });
});
```

I tried click event on `<a>` tag inside the `<div>`, didn't work.
I am sure javascript file is loading. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the `window.open("")` statement to debug? If so, don't do that! Otherwise, I can't see the logic of your code. That code could be blocked by a plugin or configuration on your browser.

Comment: you could try to see on the console if you get any error, I put your code on jsfiddle and works correctly

Comment: There is no error on console and breakpoint does not hit inside the function.

Comment: You are just defining ID. how do you open new page?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour first thing is I need to see if that click event is happening, currently if I set a breakpoint it does not get hit.

Comment: add alert(id) to check if click happens.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uw7nqx5z/ here is your code, I just put an alert and is returning the id, maybe you need to verify if jquery is defined because you are using jquery, try to put it inside a `$(function(){ //your code });` maybe you are trying to use jquery before the content is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div id="results">
    <ul class="contents">
        <li>
            <a href="your link"><div id="1" class="item">
                <div class="center">1. </div>
                <div class="center"><strong>ABook</strong></div>
                <div class="center">Description</div>
            </div></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="2" class="item">
                <div class="center">2. </div>
                <div class="center"><strong>BBook</strong></div>
                <div class="center">Description</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="3" class="item">
                <div class="center">3. </div>
                <div class="center"><strong>CBook</strong></div>
                <div class="center">Description</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div align="center">
        <ul class="pagen">
            <li class="first active">1</li>
            <li><a href="#" data-page="2" title="Page 2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-page="3" title="Page 3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-page="4" title="Next">&gt;</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#" data-page="4" title="Last">»</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here' try this. I put the  tag on the outside of the div.

Comment: This works, although still can not figure out why click event is not working.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code in a runtime function. also omit return false:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".item").click(function(e){ 
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        //code to open new window or change window location according to ID
 });

});
```

Comment: It is inside document.ready, I'm putting breakpoint at "var id= ", it does not get hit

Comment: you have to omit return false. Did you that?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not seeing any advantage of using a `div` to navigate to different page unless you want to do some preprocessing and then navigate. I've added an alert as you mentioned that the click event is not happening at all.

In that case, you may need to add the link via `data` attribute and inside the `click` handler you must use `window.location.href` to navigate to that page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".item").click(function(e){ 
    var id = $(this).attr("id"),
        href = $(this).data("link");
    alert("id : "+id);
   
    window.location.href= href;
 });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<div id="results">
    <ul class="contents">
        <li>
            <div id="1" class="item" data-link="http://www.google.com">
                <div class="center">1. </div>
                <div class="center"><strong>ABook</strong></div>
                <div class="center">Description</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="2" class="item"  data-link="http://www.google.com">
                <div class="center">2. </div>
                <div class="center"><strong>BBook</strong></div>
                <div class="center">Description</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="3" class="item" data-link="http://www.google.com">
                <div class="center">3. </div>
                <div class="center"><strong>CBook</strong></div>
                <div class="center">Description</div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div align="center">
        <ul class="pagen">
            <li class="first active">1</li>
            <li><a href="#" data-page="2" title="Page 2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-page="3" title="Page 3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-page="4" title="Next">&gt;</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#" data-page="4" title="Last">»</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

For navigation, I would prefer wrapping the `div` using  `anchor` tag and bind click event to that.

Comment: I ran your code snippet, here it works fine but for some reason this is not working with my code still no hit to breakpoint, trying to figure out what is wrong.. although putting <div> inside <a> tag works fine.

Comment: yup that should be your idle solution. But you can do in this way as well.

Comment: If its a live site, link to that site else setup a jsfiddle to figure out the JS issue.